# Converting indexed array to normal or simple array

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.4

I am trying to convert indexed array to normal array. Basically what get is:

```
Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 19 [2] => 20 )
```

And I need is:

```
Array(14,19,20);
```

I tried over Google but not information found. I think this kind of function isn't available in PHP, is there any? please let me know!

Thanks,
Asif

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're chasing shadows:
Both of the arrays you've shown are equal.

There is no such thing as an unindexed array in PHP.

But if you really want to be sure, use `$newArray = array_values($array)`

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to query with wordpress tax_query but it doesn't seems to work. So I checked on WordPress docs and found that simple array without indexed is used.

Comment: All arrays that are not associative (strings as keys) have numeric indices. Your problem is likely to be somewhere else.

Comment: @Capripio All arrays have some sort of index.

Comment: @MightyPork Are sets a type of array?

Comment: @StephenTG Okay.. only a data structure. My bad.

Comment: hmm, Yup thanks for answer I have found, Some how taxonomy's terms doesn't save! I am rechecking it!

Comment: I disagree with the rationale given by @MightyPork, especially since @Capripio mentioned WP. Let's say you have a comma-separated list which you explode into array `exploded`. Using `exploded` as an argument in a function won't work until you 'reset' the array with `array_values`.

Comment: @adamrowe can you give a concrete example of that?

Comment: @MightyPork: WP-specific example follows.

In my case, I had a comma-separated list of values stored for later use with WP's `has_tag`. This function wants an array instead. I couldn't just explode the string because the function needs the array in 'simple' format, as in `array('val1','val2','val3')`. So in this case, only the `array_values` from an exploded comma-separated list can be given to `has_tag`.

Comment: @adamrowe I meant a real working example, I'm curious what your _real_ problem was. Cause both `var_dump(explode(',', 'aa,bb,cc'));` and `var_dump(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']);` give exactly identical output.

Comment: FYI three years late to the convo: Another example are API functions that want a simple "array of strings" and won't work if they receive a numerically indexed array.