# Convert array to normal display?

Tags: php, arrays

I set my *foreach* result in a array variable, the array give me some id's,

`$categoryIDs = explode(',', $result->category_id);`

I tried already to find solution but nothing works, any sources are:
[Converting indexed array to normal or simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980095/converting-indexed-array-to-normal-or-simple-array)
[How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)
[Display array elements as normal CSV - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321698/display-array-elements-as-normal-csv-php)

If i show result with *print_r()* i see correct result, but how can i convert it into: 32,432,21,543?

Comment: You should post `var_dump()`'s of the variables concerned, but you are probably looking for `implode()` instead of `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implode` for this:

```
implode(",", $categoryIDs);
```

You can read the document [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: For coherence, I recommend using implode instead of join. Indeed, while implode() and join() are aliases, split() has a different behaviour than explode()

Comment: Agree! Actually I will just take it off the answer.